# how do I get my mac to recognize a mass storage device

Tags: macos, mac, storage

I can't get my mac to recognize an external mass storage device

Comment: What have this to do with jquery?

Comment: Oh, and you really should tell us what kind of errors you are getting, what mac-os you are running and what kind of mass-storage device you have.

Comment: Hope he won't get mad at me.. >.> :)

Comment: What's the result from typing `ls /Volumes` in Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Plug it in, open up Disk Utility, and see if anything shows up there.

`Applications` => `Utilities` => `Disk Utility`